# How to compare values in non-identically labelled pandas dataframe objects?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two dataframes with different labels, `df1` and `df2`.

`df1` contains (amongst other things) a list of time intervals (start/stop). 
`df2` contains a list of events with timestamps.

I want to check which time intervals in `df1` include an event from `df2`. It doesn't matter which specific event, and it doesn't matter how many events. Yes/No is enough.

*What I have (simplified):*

**df1**

```
 Index  Start_time  Stop_time (other columns...)
 1      1           5
 2      8           10
 3      20          22
 4      23          40
```

**df2**

```
Index  Event_time (other columns...)
1      2
2      400
3      21
4      40
```

*What I want:*

**df3**

```
 Index  Start_time  Stop_time Event Event_time(optional) (other columns...)
 1      1           5         Yes   2
 2      8           10        No    NaN
 3      20          22        Yes   21
 4      23          40        Yes   40
```

Note that (other columns) are different in both dataframes. Therefore, a direct comparison yields the `Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects`-error.

**How to compare values in non-identically labelled pandas dataframe objects?**

EDIT: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37614489/comparing-pandas-dataframe-to-series) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40567851/nested-queries-comparing-multiple-datasets-efficiently-in-pandas) looks like it is applicable here, but no results so far

Comment: In my opinion for fast solution need numpy, so I add `numpy` tag.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [series between](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
df = df[df['event_time'].between(<Start_time>, <Stop_time>, inclusive=True)]
```

EDIT:

```
In [151]
df1  = pd.DataFrame({'Start_time':[1,8,20,23], 'Stop_time':[5,10,22,40]})

In [152]
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Event_time':[2, 400, 21, 40]})

In [153]
df2['Event'] = df2['Event_time'].between(df1['Start_time'], df1['Stop_time'], inclusive=True)

In [154]
df2
Out [154]:
   Event_time  Event
0           2   True
1         400  False
2          21   True
3          40   True
```

Comment: the challenge is that df2 includes thousands of events, and the code runs once every 5 minutes. Therefore, the <Start_time> and <Stop_time> needs to be filled automatically.

Comment: Made an edit, consider accepting if it fixed your problem

Comment: I followed your instructions exactly and am still getting ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects (not Dataframe objects, which is new)

Comment: Try sorting the index first and let me know if it works

Comment: did that acording to the link below: doesn't work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548370/pandas-can-only-compare-identically-labeled-dataframe-objects-error

Comment: If you could add a representation of your data we can use as a proof of concept edit your question and I will see what I can do